# Using conditional to show a certain view upon logic

Tags: swiftui

How would I add ViewModifiers to a conditional view without repeating them?
I find myself in the following issue:
My screen loads a list but if the data array is empty then shows a view that basically says that the data is empty.
I share the code of how I'm doing it:

```
struct OverviewScreen: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: OverviewViewModel = OverviewViewModel()
    @State private var navigateToAddPillScreen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            if viewModel.viewState.isListEmpty {
                EmptyListView()
                    .sheet(isPresented: $navigateToAddPillScreen, content: {
                        AddPillScreen {
                            viewModel.getPills()
                            self.navigateToAddPillScreen.toggle()
                        }
                    })
                    .onAppear {
                        print("or here")
                        viewModel.getPills()
                    }
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem {
                            AddPillButton {
                                navigateToAddPillScreen.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                    .navigationTitle("overview")
            } else {
                List {
                    Section("today") {
                        ForEach(viewModel.pills, id: \.id) { pill in
                            PillItem(pill: pill)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        AddPillButton {
                            navigateToAddPillScreen.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $navigateToAddPillScreen, content: {
                    AddPillScreen {
                        viewModel.getPills()
                        self.navigateToAddPillScreen.toggle()
                    }
                })
                .onAppear {
                    print("is it here")
                    viewModel.getPills()
                }
                .navigationTitle("overview")
            }
            
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have to repeat the same ViewModifiers in both sentences of the If because it doesn't let me apply them outside the if.
I have the feeling this is wrong, which would be a good approach for this issue?
Thanks.

add ViewModifiers to a conditional view without repeating them

Answer (score 0):

In most cases I suggest that you try and split your code to more functions. In your case I would start in the following direction:

```
struct OverviewScreen: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: OverviewViewModel = OverviewViewModel()
    @State private var navigateToAddPillScreen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            mainContentView()
                .onAppear {
                    print("or here")
                    viewModel.getPills()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $navigateToAddPillScreen, content: {
                    AddPillScreen {
                        viewModel.getPills()
                        self.navigateToAddPillScreen.toggle()
                    }
                })
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        AddPillButton {
                            navigateToAddPillScreen.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
    private func mainContentView() -> some View {
        if viewModel.viewState.isListEmpty {
            return EmptyListView()
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                .navigationTitle("overview")
                .asAnyView()
        } else {
            return List {
                Section("today") {
                    ForEach(viewModel.pills, id: \.id) { pill in
                        PillItem(pill: pill)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("overview")
            .asAnyView()
        }
    }
    
}

extension View {
    
    func asAnyView() -> some View {
        AnyView(self)
    }
    
}
```

Now your main content view will return whatever view you will need to display. And on it you can apply modifiers all in one place.

There is a bit of inconvenience that you will need to convert the if-statement to return type of `AnyView`. There are other ways, such as wrapping it in `ZStack` but you can choose whatever solution you want.

But mostly using this approach we can clean up your code quite a lot. See another iteration:

```
struct OverviewScreen: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: OverviewViewModel = OverviewViewModel()
    @State private var navigateToAddPillScreen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            mainContentView()
                .onAppear(perform: viewModel.getPills)
                .sheet(isPresented: $navigateToAddPillScreen, content: sheetContent)
                .toolbar(content: toolbarContent)
        }
    }
    
    private func sheetContent() -> some View {
        AddPillScreen {
            viewModel.getPills()
            self.navigateToAddPillScreen.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    private func toolbarContent() -> some View {
        ToolbarItem {
            AddPillButton {
                navigateToAddPillScreen.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func mainContentView() -> some View {
        if viewModel.viewState.isListEmpty {
            return emptyListView()
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                    .navigationTitle("overview")
                    .asAnyView()
        } else {
            return listView(pills: viewModel.pills)
                    .navigationTitle("overview")
                    .asAnyView()
        }
    }
    
    private func emptyListView() -> some View {
        EmptyListView()
    }
    
    private func listView(pills: [Pill]) -> some View {
        List {
            Section("today") {
                ForEach(pills, id: \.id) { pill in
                    PillItem(pill: pill)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I hope this helps you solve your problem and hopefully some others you may encounter as result of not splitting your views.

Comment: Interesting that you prefer `func`tions and not `@ViewBuilder var`. Is there a reason for that? or just a personal preference?

Comment: @timbretimbre Mostly `@ViewBuilder` functions to be hones. But I did not want to introduce this here in the post. Reason for functions is for consistency when adding input parameters. Like the above `func listView(pills: [Pill]) -> some View`. But I don't mind using computed properties.

Comment: @timbretimbre actually I take that back. Functions are way more usable in SwiftUI because you can do things like `Button(action: onButtonPressed, label: buttonContent)` where `buttonContent` is a function returning `some View`. You get some pushback when using it as a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. Simplest: expressed the view that changes in a separate `var`, while leaving all the common modifies as they are:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            dataBasedView // <-- this
                .sheet
                // ... - other common modifiers
}

// And now a new variable, which makes the choice
@ViewBuilder private var dataBasedView: some View {
        if viewModel.viewState.isListEmpty {
            EmptyListView()
        } else {
            List {
                Section("today") {
                    ForEach(viewModel.pills, id: \.id) { pill in
                        PillItem(pill: pill)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Opposite option is package all your common modifiers as 1 custom view modifier, and apply it for each of them:

```
extension View {

    func myFancyViewModifier(/* parameters for modifiers */) -> some View {
         self
           .sheet
           // ... other common view modifiers
    }
}
```

And now you just apply this new modifier to all your views:

```
if viewModel.viewState.isListEmpty {
    EmptyListView()
    .myFancyViewModifier(...)
} else {
    List {
       Section("today") { .... }
    }
    .myFancyViewModifier(...)
```

This is suitable when you have a bunch of modifiers with not many parameters, which you keep reusing on many screens and views in the same way (for example colors, styling, etc). I would say for your specific modifiers this is not suitable, but as you asked a general question, this sometimes fits.

3. And another options, especially if you are dealing with a bunch of common behaviors across multiple screens / views is to express them *as* view, which as part of setup can accept another view for contents:

```
struct Screen<Content: View>: View {

    let title: String
    
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .sheet
            .navigationTitle(title)
            // any common modifiers you want to have on every screen
    }
}
```

And then you use it as

```
if viewModel.viewState.isListEmpty {
     Screen(title: "overview", content: EmptyListView())
} else {
     Screen(title: "overview", content: List { ... })
```